# How to divide a map into circles of a given radius?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, geometry, geocoding, geospatial

Folks,

How can I take a state and divide it into areas that are 50 miles in radius?

Perhaps there's a better way to solve my problem: I have a list of 700 locations with unique city names. Some cities are less than 50 miles apart. I need to reduce that list to the minimal number of locations that are no more than 50 miles away and that basically cover the nearby cities in the list. This way I can find the center radius ZIP code of each of the location on the reduced list and then search for "stores within 50 miles", which should return all 700 locations.

Update: I have 5000 products and 700 stores in different cities. I need to check inventory for ALL products. The site where I check it only shows inventory in stores that are within 50 miles of a given city. That mean that I need to make 3,500,000 requests. Hence, I am looking for a way to reduce 700 stores to a smaller number.

Comment: You can't divide an area into circles without either overlap or having gaps.

Comment: So you want a set of circles which cover all of the 700 locations. You could use a regular array of points say circles in a honeycomb like arrangement.

Comment: @Salixalba each circle/whatever shape should have 1 point. The idea is to have as little points as possible yet when using those points to query for all points within 50 miles radius, I would get all 700 points. Overlap is fine.

Comment: @geocodezip some overlap is fine.

Comment: Does it need to be a strict minimum or will an approximate solution do?

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means this does something similar using Gaussian rather than circles. You might be able to adapt the algorithms.

Comment: @Salixalba an approximate solution will do if it's fast.

Answer (score 1):

A simple algorithm which would work but is far from optimal. This starts with a list of candidate towns

1. Pick a town at random, draw a circle around that point
2. Remove all towns inside the circle
3. Repeat until there are no towns left

You could run it a few times to see if some runs produce significantly fewer resulting circles.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the binary value from the x- and y co-oordinates. Instead of a straight line it orders the points along a z-curve. Then you can compute the upper bounds with the mostsignificant bits. The z-curve is often use in mapping applications:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx.